# Check a value from an MVC route to ensure its stored with a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am using MVC4 and have created a custom route within my global.asax to get the host details.

I have setup a product that gives my users the ability to log in via 'theirbusiness.mydomain.com'

I now want to check when a user browses to 'randomstore.mydomain.com' that the actual store is already created within my database if the store doesnt exist redirect the user to a page.

So far I have

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.Add(new SubDomainRoute());
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Process", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null,
            namespaces: new[] { "WebApplication.Controllers" }
        );
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}


public class SubDomainRoute : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
        log.Info(string.Format("GetRouteData"));
        log.Info(DateTime.Now);
        var url = httpContext.Request.Headers["HOST"];
        var index = url.IndexOf(".");

        if (index < 0)
            return null;
        log.Info(url);
        var subDomain = url.Substring(0, index);
        //check 


        log.Info(subDomain);

        return null;
    }
```

What is the best way for me to take the variable subDomain and check it within the database. It doesnt feel right to be trying to do it within SubDomainRoute class

Comment: Do you want this redirection for all the requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do the check/redirection for all the requests then you could easily do that in the `Application_BeginRequest` itself.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
  var host = context.Request.Headers["HOST"];

  // check the store is created in database and redirect if not exist.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, I put a breakpoint jsut for testing and is it normal for it to be called multiple times per view? I have a page that contains a few ajax calls and the BeginRequest is called everytime

Comment: Yes I think it maybe best to do it for each request, I don't want a user to log in and then be able to change it after login